# Use different authentication methods for OpenSSH server depending on client IP

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm sure this has been answered before, but I could not locate the answer with Google, and this search.  I currently only allow shared key authentication for openssh server on my box.  However, I would like to be able to use password auth, when I am connecting locally, via my internal (192.168.1.x) subnet.

Is it possible to use a per-host authentication method in OpenSSH?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Match` directive in [`/etc/sshd_config`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config).

```
PasswordAuthentication No
Match Address 192.168.1.0/24
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

You can restrict this to a few users (who you trust not to choose terrible passwords), for better security.

```
PasswordAuthentication No
Match Address 192.168.1.0/24 User joe,bob
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! If only I had known that one word, 'Match'!

Comment: So I finally tried this, and it does not work:
`Directive 'PasswordAuthentication' is not allowed within a Match block`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That's really weird: I've used this setup several times, and it's always worked for me. What version of OpenSSH are you using, under what OS?

Comment: "OpenSSH_4.4p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8d 28 Sep 2006" on SuSE 10.3.  I'm in the process of upgrading now (which is why I wanted to look into this)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ah, that would explain it, your version is too old. `PasswordAuthentication` has been permitted in `Match` blocks only since [`servconf.c` 1.168](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/servconf.c#rev1.168) which first shipped in OpenSSH 4.6.